# Jersey REST client request - how to set source ip address

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-client

I have a system with many Ethernet interfaces like eth0, eth1, eth3 etc., with different ip address configured for each of those.

My application deployed on this system, acts as REST client and it will make request to two servers A and B. The requirement is while sending REST request to Server A, the source ip address should be "eth0" ip address and while sending request to server B, I should use "eth1" ip address.

I make the client request using the code below

```
client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(node.getUrl());
webTarget = target.path(path).resolveTemplatesFromEncoded(pathValues);
Builder builder = webTarget.request();
response = builder.post(entity);
```

I thought I can set the source ip address in 'client', but could not find any method to do it. Can you give me some idea how to set this source ip address for client requests?

Comment: You would have to somehow use custom SocketFactory with Jersey. Not an easy task :/

Answer (score 0):

If eth0, eth1... are in different ip domaine the OS will resolve that and use the best interface.
If not  [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html)
so you need to find the socket under the client and I don't know if jersey lets an access to it.